# long string html data split in python

Tags: python

I have string. just like this:

```
 " fill="#185CC6"></path></g></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="1.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="
    M275 764 c-103 -37 -194 -110 -228 -184 -81 -174 -56 -342 67 -466
    154 -153 398 -153 552 0 123 124 148 292 67 466 -21 44 -109 132 -153 153
    -105 48 -221 60 -305 31z m179 -123 c3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136
    -136 4 -17 11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19
    -15 -36 -8 -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -3 -5 -32 -9 -64
" fill="#185CC6"></path></g></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="2.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="2"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player Banker"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="
    M288 767 c-28 -11 -38 -40 -18 -52 6 -3 10 -22 10 -41 0 -37 22 -56
    43 -35 13 13 123 15 131 2 3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136 -136 4 -17
    11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19 -15 -36 -8
    -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -7 -12 -121 -12 -128 0 -3 4
    19 -212 3z
" fill="#185CC6"></path></g><circle cx="10" cy="14" r="10" fill="#C52123"></circle></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="3.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="3"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="
    M275 764 c-103 -37 -194 -110 -228 -184 -81 -174 -56 -342 67 -466
    154 -153 398 -153 552 0 123 124 148 292 67 466 -21 44 -109 132 -153 153
    -105 48 -221 60 -305 31z m179 -123 c3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136
    -136 4 -17 11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19
    -15 -36 -8 -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -3 -5 -32 -9 -64
 ...
```

I want to split this string justlike:

```
[" fill="#185CC6"></path></g></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="1.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="
        M275 764 c-103 -37 -194 -110 -228 -184 -81 -174 -56 -342 67 -466
        154 -153 398 -153 552 0 123 124 148 292 67 466 -21 44 -109 132 -153 153
        -105 48 -221 60 -305 31z m179 -123 c3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136
        -136 4 -17 11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19
        -15 -36 -8 -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -3 -5 -32 -9 -64
 ,
" fill="#185CC6"></path></g></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="2.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="2"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player Banker"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="
        M288 767 c-28 -11 -38 -40 -18 -52 6 -3 10 -22 10 -41 0 -37 22 -56
        43 -35 13 13 123 15 131 2 3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136 -136 4 -17
        11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19 -15 -36 -8
        -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -7 -12 -121 -12 -128 0 -3 4
        -19 11 -36 15 -38 7 -127 94 -136 133 -4 15 -11 33 -16 40 -5 6 -8 37 -7 67 1
 ,
...
]
```

I cannot find where to split this data. I don't think this string has any splitable part, or characteristic.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split by the newline character(`\n`) that is not visible in your string, but is there wherever  `" fill="#185CC6"` starts on a new line:

```
text = ''' " fill="#185CC6"></path></g></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="1.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="
    M275 764 c-103 -37 -194 -110 -228 -184 -81 -174 -56 -342 67 -466
    154 -153 398 -153 552 0 123 124 148 292 67 466 -21 44 -109 132 -153 153
    -105 48 -221 60 -305 31z m179 -123 c3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136
    -136 4 -17 11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19
    -15 -36 -8 -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -3 -5 -32 -9 -64
" fill="#185CC6"></path></g></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="2.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="2"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player Banker"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="
    M288 767 c-28 -11 -38 -40 -18 -52 6 -3 10 -22 10 -41 0 -37 22 -56
    43 -35 13 13 123 15 131 2 3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136 -136 4 -17
    11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19 -15 -36 -8
    -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -7 -12 -121 -12 -128 0 -3 4
    19 -212 3z
" fill="#185CC6"></path></g><circle cx="10" cy="14" r="10" fill="#C52123"></circle></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="3.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="3"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="
    M275 764 c-103 -37 -194 -110 -228 -184 -81 -174 -56 -342 67 -466
    154 -153 398 -153 552 0 123 124 148 292 67 466 -21 44 -109 132 -153 153
    -105 48 -221 60 -305 31z m179 -123 c3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136
    -136 4 -17 11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19
    -15 -36 -8 -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -3 -5 -32 -9 -64'''

result = [' " fill' + i for n, i in enumerate(text.split('\n" fill')) if not n == 0]
```

Output:

```
[' " fill="#185CC6"></path></g></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="1.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="1"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="\n    M275 764 c-103 -37 -194 -110 -228 -184 -81 -174 -56 -342 67 -466\n    154 -153 398 -153 552 0 123 124 148 292 67 466 -21 44 -109 132 -153 153\n    -105 48 -221 60 -305 31z m179 -123 c3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136\n    -136 4 -17 11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19\n    -15 -36 -8 -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -3 -5 -32 -9 -64',
 ' " fill="#185CC6"></path></g></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="2.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="2"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player Banker"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="\n    M288 767 c-28 -11 -38 -40 -18 -52 6 -3 10 -22 10 -41 0 -37 22 -56\n    43 -35 13 13 123 15 131 2 3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136 -136 4 -17\n    11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19 -15 -36 -8\n    -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -7 -12 -121 -12 -128 0 -3 4\n    19 -212 3z',
 ' " fill="#185CC6"></path></g><circle cx="10" cy="14" r="10" fill="#C52123"></circle></svg></svg></svg><svg width="0.95" height="0.95" x="0.05" y="3.05" data-type="coordinates" data-x="0" data-y="3"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="svg--1sK_i" viewBox="0 0 80 80" data-type="roadItem" name="Player"><defs></defs><svg width="68px" height="68px" x="6" y="6" viewBox="0 0 80 80"><g transform="translate(0,78) scale(0.1,-0.1)" fill="#185CC6" stroke="none" data-type="roadItemColor"><path d="\n    M275 764 c-103 -37 -194 -110 -228 -184 -81 -174 -56 -342 67 -466\n    154 -153 398 -153 552 0 123 124 148 292 67 466 -21 44 -109 132 -153 153\n    -105 48 -221 60 -305 31z m179 -123 c3 -4 19 -11 36 -15 40 -8 128 -96 136\n    -136 4 -17 11 -33 15 -36 5 -3 9 -32 9 -64 0 -32 -4 -61 -9 -64 -4 -3 -11 -19\n    -15 -36 -8 -40 -96 -128 -136 -136 -17 -4 -33 -11 -36 -15 -3 -5 -32 -9 -64']
```